# jquery touch functions cross browser issue and error output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I have a slider that I made for my website which seems to work correctly in chrome mobile. However, it outputs error codes which I am not sure how to correct...also on safari mobile the 'leftswipe' animation does not work.

Here is the errors in the console:

[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive.

See 
home.js:49 Uncaught ReferenceError: $turn is not defined

here is the js:

```
$(window).bind('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault()});
$('#content').empty().load('mobileslides.php #mbhome1', function() {

  var $page = 1;

  $(document).on('touchstart', function(e) {
    $('#content').removeAttr('class');
    $firstT = e.touches[0].clientX;
    $center = $(window).width() / 2;
    $turn = 0;

    $(this).on('touchmove', function(e) {
       $lastT = e.changedTouches[0].clientX;
       $distance = 0;

      if ( $firstT < $lastT ){
        $distance = -($firstT) + $lastT
        $('#content').css('transform', 'translateX(' + $distance + 'px)');
      } else {
        $distance = $firstT - $lastT;
        $('#content').css('transform', 'translateX(-' + $distance + 'px)');
      }



      if( ($firstT < $center) && ($lastT > $center) && ($distance > 85) ){
        $('#content').removeAttr('style').addClass('prels');
        $turn = 'left';

      }

      if( ($firstT > $center) && ($lastT < $center) && ($distance > 85) ){
        $('#content').removeAttr('style').addClass('prers');
        $turn = 'right';

      }
    });


    $(this).on('touchend', function() {

      if ( $turn == 0 ) {

        $('#content').animate({opacity: '1'}, 200);
        $('#content').css('transform', 'translateX(0)');

      }

      if( $turn == 'left'){

        $page = $page - 1;

        if ($page < 1) {
          $page = 5;
        }

        if ( $page == 1 ){
          $('#content').load('mobileslides.php #mbhome1', function (){
            $('#content').addClass('leftswipe');
          });
        }

        if ( $page == 2 ){
          $('#content').load('mobileslides.php #mbhome2', function (){
            $('#content').addClass('leftswipe');
          });
        }

        if ( $page == 3 ){
          $('#content').load('mobileslides.php #mbhome3', function (){
            $('#content').addClass('leftswipe');
          });
        }

        if ( $page == 4 ){
          $('#content').load('mobileslides.php #mbhome4', function (){
            $('#content').addClass('leftswipe');
          });
        }

        if ( $page == 5 ){
          $('#content').load('mobileslides.php #mbhome5', function (){
            $('#content').addClass('leftswipe');
          });
        }
      }

      if( $turn == 'right'){

        $page = $page + 1;

        if ($page > 5) {
          $page = 1;
        }

        if ( $page == 1 ){
          $('#content').load('mobileslides.php #mbhome1', function (){
            $('#content').addClass('rightswipe');
          });
        }

        if ( $page == 2 ){
          $('#content').load('mobileslides.php #mbhome2', function (){
            $('#content').addClass('rightswipe');
          });
        }

        if ( $page == 3 ){
          $('#content').load('mobileslides.php #mbhome3', function (){
            $('#content').addClass('rightswipe');
          });
        }

        if ( $page == 4 ){
          $('#content').load('mobileslides.php #mbhome4', function (){
            $('#content').addClass('rightswipe');
          });
        }

        if ( $page == 5 ){
          $('#content').load('mobileslides.php #mbhome5', function (){
            $('#content').addClass('rightswipe');
          });
        }

      }

      delete $firstT;
      delete $lastT;
      delete $distance;
      delete $turn;

    });
  });




});
```

here is the relevant css

```
.mbhome{
          display: block;
          text-align: center;
        }

#content{
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
@keyframes leftswipe{
    from {transform: : translateX(-150%); opacity: 0;}
    to {transform: translateX(0%); opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes rightswipe{
    from {transform: : translateX(150%); opacity: 0;}
    to {transform: translateX(0%); opacity: 1;}
}
.leftswipe{
    animation-name: leftswipe;
    animation-duration: 200ms;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.rightswipe{
    animation-name: leftswipe;
    animation-duration: 200ms;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.prels{
    transform: translateX(-150%);
}

.prers {
    transform: translateX(150%);
}
```

and here is the slides so its easy to recreate

```
 <div id="mbhome1" class="mbhome">
 <h1 class="firsttext"> Our firm breeds winners...</h1>
 <p> &#60; swipe left or right to navigate &#62; </p>
 <div id="debug">
    <p>First touch was:</p>
    <p>Last Touch was:</p>
    <p>Distance was:</p>
    <p>Center is:</p>
    <p></p>
    <p>Page number is:1</p>
 </div>
 </div>

<div id="mbhome2" class="mbhome">
<h1 class="firsttext"> Our firm breeds winners...</h1>
<p> &#60; swipe left or right to navigate &#62; </p>
<div id="debug">
    <p>First touch was:</p>
    <p>Last Touch was:</p>
    <p>Distance was:</p>
    <p>Center is:</p>
    <p></p>
    <p>Page number is:2</p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="mbhome3" class="mbhome">
<h1 class="firsttext"> Our firm breeds winners...</h1>
<p> &#60; swipe left or right to navigate &#62; </p>
<div id="debug">
    <p>First touch was:</p>
    <p>Last Touch was:</p>
    <p>Distance was:</p>
    <p>Center is:</p>
    <p></p>
    <p>Page number is:3</p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="mbhome4" class="mbhome">
<h1 class="firsttext"> Our firm breeds winners...</h1>
<p> &#60; swipe left or right to navigate &#62; </p>
<div id="debug">
    <p>First touch was:</p>
    <p>Last Touch was:</p>
    <p>Distance was:</p>
    <p>Center is:</p>
    <p></p>
    <p>Page number is:4</p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="mbhome5" class="mbhome">
<h1 class="firsttext"> Our firm breeds winners...</h1>
<p> &#60; swipe left or right to navigate &#62; </p>
<div id="debug">
    <p>First touch was:</p>
    <p>Last Touch was:</p>
    <p>Distance was:</p>
    <p>Center is:</p>
    <p></p>
    <p>Page number is:5</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have `touchmove` and `touchend` event handlers nested into `touchstart`. So you're adding more and more of them on **every** `touchstart`. It would be better to move them out. Also I do not see `touchcancel` event handler which is necessary to handle situation when a finger swipes out of the screen.

Comment: ohhhh my gosh that explains alot of the script overload i could not figure out! and i do not have a touch cancel event...thanks alot ill see how this goes:))